# I have issues in understanding term Task CLASSPATH in Hadoop for MapReduce.

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have issues in understanding term Task CLASSPATH in Hadoop for MapReduce. Whats exactly this term means and how it can cause conflict with CLIENT CLASSPATH

Comment: It's possible for the JVM classpath on the client side (e.g. where you run the `hadoop jar` command)j to differ from the classpath of JVM processes that run the map and reduce tasks distributed across the cluster.  Does this help?  Is there some additional context that would clarify your question, such as documentation you found that discusses the classpath?

Comment: Thanks man that helped, but if we put right jars both on JVM classpath on the client side and JVM classpath for map and reduce tasks, that should solve the problem of conflict. If we can set same classpath by any means for both JVM that you mentioned, it should serve the purpose of resolving conflict. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.  Making the classpath consistent on both the client and the map/reduce tasks would prevent problems like version conflicts.